# 2011 Moderator Election - Town Hall Chat: midnight UTC on 16th (7pm EST on the 15th!) - now!

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Wednesday the 16th at midnight UTC, or 7pm EST on the 15th.**

**[(view in other timezones)](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=2&day=16&year=2011&hour=0&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[click here to join](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/285/seasoned-advice-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase, so I am looking at the 14th-17th.  As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=cooking.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/285/seasoned-advice-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: D'oh. I'm an idiot. I read 7pm EST and I saw the 16th. I even aranged my day snowboarding to be able to make it. But I've already missed it. If that's not a vote of no confidence, I'm not sure what is!

Comment: @yossarian You can read up on the questions in the Town Hall Chat Room, and provide your own answers post-fact for the digest, still. Don't worry too much about it, one of the Gaming candidates made the same day-of-event mistake you did.

Comment: The whole UTC thing almost tripped me up too @yossarian.

Comment: @yossarian yes, please just post your answers in the Town Hall Chat (or any other chat) and notify me. I will include them in [the digest](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest). Please do post them in chat, that way I can keep a consistent format. Thanks!

Comment: @Josh, I will try and see if I can find a computer and some time. Doing it on phone would take forever.

Answer (score 1):

As with the other town hall chats, I will be creating a "digest" version for the Cooking Town Hall Chat. This will be posted as one large Meta question. The digest will contain all the questions and their answers, with none of the other conversation from the room.

For more information, please see [the meta post about Town Hall Digests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77831/how-can-we-improve-the-town-hall-digests). Or for an example, look at the [AskUbuntu Town Hall Digest](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/948/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest) or the [Gaming Town Hall Digest](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1759/2252).

**[Here is the Digest version of the Town Hall Chat](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/2011-moderator-election-town-hall-chat-digest)**.